# Fill Data to control from success response which is on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I bring my `ajax` response on success call and after that I want to redirect to new aspx page where all my `30 input type text` controls are their. So What I want is I want to fill all the values their. So how could I achieve it. Please suggest.

Here is what I tried till now

```
function getDataForDashboard(rjSapId) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetDashboardDataOnFacId",
            data: JSON.stringify({ rjSapId: rjSapId }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {                    
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:39800/DashboardData.aspx?Id=" + rjSapId + "";
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('Something went wrong..!!');
            }
        });

    }
```

The another page some controls are below:-

```
<span>Site Type:</span>

<input type="text" id="txtSiteType" />
<br />

<span>Facility Type:</span>

<input type="text" id="txtFacilityType" />
<br />
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826979/How-to-Send-Data-from-One-aspx-Page-to-Another-usi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can save all your data in a hidden field by doing a stringify or, save it in local storage and then in the next page ajax ready you can retrieve it